# The problem with calling constructor from nested abstract parent class

Tags: c++, constructor

I have the following code snippet and expect that constructor from parent class `First::Inner` will be called.

```
class First {
    public:
        class Inner {
            public:
                Inner(int x) {}
                virtual ~Inner() = default;
        };
        virtual Inner* begin() = 0;
};

class Second: public First {
    public:
        class Inner: public First::Inner {
        };
        Inner* begin() {
            return new Inner(1);
        }
};

int main()
{
    Second s;

    return 0;
}
```

Instead I got a compile error in the compiler:

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘virtual Second::Inner* Second::begin()’:
main.cpp:16:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘Second::Inner::Inner(int)’
```

It works if moved the entire constructor `Inner(int x) {}` from base class `First::Inner` to derived `Second::Inner`. But I'd like to keep the constructor in the base class.

What's wrong with the code and how could I fix the error?

Comment: This behavior isn't really related to nesting classes. You could get rid of `First` and `Second`, rename `First::Inner` to `A`, rename `Second::Inner` to `B` (inheriting `A`), and any function trying to initialize a `B` with an `int` would give a similar error.

Comment: The message means exactly what it says.  `Second::Inner` does not have a constructor that accents an argument of type `int`.   The fact there is one in `First::Inner` doesn't cause one to be generated for `Second::Inner`.   You can implement the constructor for `Second::Inner` so it initialises its base, by calling `First::Inner`s constructor with an `int`, in the initialiser list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the class `Second::Inner` doesn't have a constructor taking `int`, then `new Inner(1);` would fail.

You can [inherit constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors) like

```
class Inner: public First::Inner {
    using First::Inner::Inner;
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Gm5OMUjZaBYdWZbp)

> If the using-declaration refers to a constructor of a direct base of
>   the class being defined (e.g. `using Base::Base;`), all constructors of
>   that base (ignoring member access) are made visible to overload
>   resolution when initializing the derived class.
>
> If overload resolution selects one of the inherited constructors when
>   initializing an object of such derived class, then the Base subobject
>   from which the constructor was inherited is initialized using the
>   inherited constructor, and all other bases and members of Derived are
>   initialized as if by the defaulted default constructor (default member
>   initializers are used if provided, otherwise default initialization
>   takes place). The entire initialization is treated as a single
>   function call: initialization of the parameters of the inherited
>   constructor is sequenced-before initialization of any base or member
>   of the derived object.